# Why can't I create temporary tablespace?

Tags: oracle, tablespaces

I'm trying to create dictionary managed tablespace with the `TEMPORARY` clause and `TEMPFILE` clause of `CREATE TABLESPACE`  statement. But oracle says I can't use the `DEFAULT STORAGE` clause doing that... What is the error here ?

```
CREATE TABLESPACE myTempTableSpace
TEMPFILE '/home/folder/tempfile.dbf' size 1M
DEFAULT STORAGE 
(
INITIAL 1M
PCTINCREASE 0
)
TEMPORARY
EXTENT MANAGEMENT DICTIONARY;
```

The error is :

> ORA-02180: invalid option for CREATE TABLESPACE

Answer (score 1):

To create a temp tablespace, the syntax is `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLESPACE`, not `CREATE TABLESPACE`.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLESPACE myTempTableSpace
  TEMPFILE '/home/folder/tempfile.dbf' SIZE 1M
;
```

I wouldn't set any storage clauses, unless you have a good reason to do so.

Documentation link [here](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_7003.htm#CJAFDEIF).

Comment: I know that syntax. But for learning purpose, I want to create a temporary dictionnary managed tablespace using the `CREATE TABLESPACE` statment with its `TEMPORARY` clause because I want to manually edit the `DEFAULT STORAGE` clause and make the tablespace `DICTIONNARY MANAGED`

Comment: [The Fine Manual] (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_7003.htm#i2096553) says why you cannot make it dictionary managed. See the restrictions bit.

Comment: For what learning purposes?  It's something you would never have reason to do.  Dictionary managed TS is obsolete, and only kept around for backward compatibility.